# Objective C Odatagen tool

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am new to odata wcf data services. I am trying to use odatagen tool on terminal on mac os in order to generate proxy classes.

I am getting "command not found" error though I am executing below command from the correct path.

macuser-imac:Desktop macuser$ odatagen /uri=http://localhost:13986/NorthWindDataServices.svc /out=/Users/macuser/Desktop/odatagenapp

can anyone help me or is there are any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's in the path?  Even if the odatagen command is in the same directory it won't necessarily be found.  If that's the case, try:  ./odatagen /url...
to ensure it looks in the current directory.